# Windows service install doesn't have correct privileges

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a service that I have created for Windows. The service works fine. The problem I am having is a permission issue. My service accesses a `.mdf` SQL Server database file that is created when the service is installed (using Installshield VS 2012).

The service itself is running as user. When I install I input my credentials and I can successfully start the service. The service starts fine. However, when I get to the part in my code where I have to open the `.mdf` I get an error because the database log file does not exists and the service does not have permissions to create it.

The only way I can fix it is by adding my username or authenticated users for example to the security section of my program files folder. This allows the SQL Server `.log` file to be created and my service continues running.

What is the best solution to getting around this? Basically I want to be able to run the service and local system and it have the privileges to install and create the `.mdf`.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: `.mdf` is a SQL Server database file - and SQL Server is a **server-based** product. The best way would be to have a SQL Server installed somewhere, install the **database** onto it (using SQL scripts) and then connect to that database using ADO.NET and the server and database names - don't fiddle around with `.mdf` files yourself! That's a mess and it'll show. If you really must have a **file-based** solution, use something else - SQL Server **Compact Edition** (with a `.sdf` file) or SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

You should create the database log file during the installation. You can run custom code during the installation to do that (the code may be similar to what triggers creation of the log file in your regular code). That will use the user with elevated permissions so it will work well and is correct from the security point of view (all administrative tasks should be done during the installation in this case).

It's better not to add permissions for a normal user to SQL Server data folder as that will lower security.